# fscanf in C with a text file with no spaces

Tags: c, scanf

I have a text file with names that looks as follows:

"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET",

I have used the following code to attempt to put the names into an array:

```
char * names[9];
int i = 0;
FILE * fp = fopen("names.txt", "r");

for (i=0; i < 9; i++) {
  fscanf(fp, "\"%s\",", names[i]);
}
```

The program comes up with a segmentation fault when I try to run it. I have debugged carefully, and I notice that the fault comes when I try and read in the second name.

Does anybody know why my code isn't working, and also why the segmentation fault is happening?

Comment: You must reserve space for the names you scan. E.g. define `char names[MAX_NAME_COUNT][MAX_NAME_LENGTH];` and read into it with the code you provided.

Comment: Your pointer array is not valid.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` or similar) and you'll see why.

Comment: The code creates an array of 9 pointers to char.  However, there is no allocation of the memory area(s) needed to hold the actual data inputs.

Comment: Your code is missing the check of the return code from fopen() so the code does not know if the fopen() was successful or failed.  Your code is missing the check of the return code from fscanf() so the code does not know if the fscanf() was successful or failed.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I admit, this was terrible code, but it still compiled with -Wall and -Werror

Comment: I am very much tempted to vote for closing this question. We see so many questions about `scanf` that are just missing to pass an appropriate buffer to it, and that have tons of duplicates on SO. But here there are actually two questions, the other which is better reflected in the title than in the text, so I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, because you don't allocate memory for the pointers you write to in the `fscanf` call.

You have an array of nine uninitialized pointers, and as they are part of a local variable they have an indeterminate value, i.e. they will point to seemingly random locations. Writing to random locations in memory (which is what will happen when you call `fscanf`) will do bad things.

The simplest way to solve the problem is to use an array of arrays, like e.g.

```
char names[9][20];
```

This will gives you an array of nine arrays, each sub-array being 20 characters (which allows you to have names up to 19 characters long).

To not write out of bounds, you should also modify your call so that you don't read to many characters:

```
fscanf(fp, "\"%19s\",", names[i]);
```

---

There is however another problem with your use of the [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function, and that is that the format to read a string, `"%s"`, reads until it finds a whitespace in the input (or until the limit is reached, if a field width is provided).

In short: You can't use `fscanf` to read your input.

Instead I suggest you read the whole line into memory at once, using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then split the string on the comma using e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

---

One way of handling arbitrarily long lines as input from a file (pseudoish-code):

```
#define SIZE 256

size_t current_size = SIZE;
char *buffer = malloc(current_size);
buffer[0] = '\0';  // Terminator at first character, makes the string empty

for (;;)
{
    // Read into temporary buffer
    char temp[SIZE];
    fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), file_pointer);

    // Append to actual buffer
    strcat(buffer, temp);

    // If last character is a newline (which `fgets` always append
    // if it reaches the end of the line) then the whole line have
    // been read and we are done
    if (last_character_is_newline(buffer))
        break;

    // Still more data to read from the line
    // Allocate a larger buffer
    current_size += SIZE;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, current_size);

    // Continues the loop to try and read the next part of the line
}

// After the loop the pointer `buffer` points to memory containing the whole line
```

[***Note:*** The above code snippet doesn't contain any error handling.]

Comment: Most of the times ;-). Once in a blue moon random things are helpful or we wouldn't be here writing this.

Comment: Thanks! I do this method and I get MARY","PATRICIA","L as the first array entry and then garbage for the rest. Why??

Comment: @lhay86 Ah yes, I forgot to write it in the answer, but the `"%s"` format reads *everything* until a whitespace in the input. You can't use it with the input you have. Will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks fgets with strtok is great! Another question: what if the text file has thousands of names? No string would be able to hold all the names. How would I modify your solution?

Comment: @lhay86 On POSIX systems (like Linux or OSX) you could use [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html). I'm sure there's a similar function for Windows (but I can't find any now), otherwise you could use `fgets` in a loop (see my updated answer for a solution).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *names[9], buff[32];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("names.txt", "r");

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(1==fscanf(fp, "\"%31[^\"]\",", buff)){//"\"%s\"," does not work like that what you want
            size_t len = strlen(buff) + 1;
            names[i] = malloc(len);//Space is required to load the strings of each
            memcpy(names[i], buff, len);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //check print & deallocate
    for(i = 0; i< 9; ++i){
        puts(names[i]);
        free(names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this means: "\"%31[^\"]\","
In particular, what is %31 and why did you include the square brackets?

Comment: The former is the maximum length (leaving space for a trailing zero byte, I guess); the square brackets indicate a pattern, in this case "everything that isn't a double quote" (note the backslash which makes it possible to have the double quote character inside a string delimited by double quotes). Normally scanf will read all chars which appear inside the square brackets; with a leading caret it will read anything *but*, which makes it read the name up to but excluding the first double quote here.

Comment: @lhay86 31 : The maximum number of characters to read, [char list] : read the specified character(read only include  char list). [^char list] : read a character other than those specified. So 31[^\"] : read 31 characters maximum of up to `"`.

Comment: And one should add that scanf's normal simple "separate items by whitespace" rule is suspended for items specified by [] syntax. That's why you can use it here. But do not get the idea to suddenly introduce whitespace in your data ;-). (It may be prudent to include whitespace in the ignore pattern and make a second -- marked to be ignored by `*` -- pattern of the trailing `\","` which right now is a ridid sequence.).

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
for (i=0; i < 9; i++) 
{
   names[i]=malloc(15);// you should take care about size
   fscanf(fp, "\"%s\",", names[i]);
}
```

Comment: And remember to `free()` each member of the array when you are done using them.